# Android, How to make a @Parcelize with builder

Tags: android, kotlin, builder, parcelable

Having a Parcelable which has a lot members, and it has a private constructor so it can only be instantiated through a Builder. (And this class is also used in Java side of the code.)
Now would like to use `@Parcelize` to remove some of the helper functions (like `writeMapToParcel` etc.) to make the class simpler.

@Parcelize requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor (that will be a long list for us).

Question, can it still use Builder patten and with a private primary constructor? Or other suggested best practice?

```
class MessageData : Parcelable {
    @JvmField var from: String = ""
    @JvmField var sentTime: Long = 0
    @JvmField var data: HashMap<String, String>

    // it has long list of members not listed here...
    
    private constructor(builder: Builder) {
        from = builder.from
        sentTime = builder.sentTime
        data = builder.data
        ......
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return hashCode()
    }

    class Builder {
        internal var from = ""
        internal var sentTime: Long = 0
        internal var data = HashMap<String, String>()
        ......

        fun setFrom(from: String?): Builder {
            this.from = from ?: ""
            return this
        }

        fun setSentTime(sentTime: Long): Builder {
            this.sentTime = sentTime
            return this
        }

        fun setData(data: HashMap<String, String>?): Builder {
            this.data = data ?: HashMap()
            return this
        }

        fun build(): MessageData {
            return MessageData(this)
        }
    }

    // Parcelable
    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        dest.writeString(from)
        dest.writeLong(sentTime)
        writeMapToParcel(dest, data)
        ......
    }

    protected constructor(p: Parcel) {
        from = p.readString() ?: ""
        sentTime = p.readLong()
        data = getMapFromParcel(p)
        ......
    }

    fun getMapFromParcel(p: Parcel): HashMap<String, String> {
        val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
        val mapSize = p.readInt()
        for (i in 0 until mapSize) {
            val key = p.readString() ?: continue
            val value = p.readString() ?: ""
            hashMap[key] = value
        }
        return hashMap
    }

    fun writeMapToParcel(dest: Parcel, map: Map<String, String>) {
        val mapSize = map.size
        dest.writeInt(mapSize)
        for ((key, value) in map) {
            dest.writeString(key)
            dest.writeString(value)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<MessageData> = object : Parcelable.Creator<MessageData> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): MessageData? {
                return MessageData(source)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MessageData?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to use the Builder pattern, but @Parcelize seems does not like the private primary constructor.